# Couchbase lite react native tracking network and replication

Tags: react-native, replication, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm a newbie in both react native and couchbase lite, and I try this sample application https://github.com/jmn8718/RNCouchbaseExample.git .

This sample, connect mobile couchbase lite db to a remote sync gateway.

But when mobile go offline, and then go online, replication not reboot or don't detect connection lost.
Do you have some idea on how to fix it ?
 Do I need to track network status myself in mobile app, or use replication with a timer ?

My actual replication code :

```
function repl() {
     database.replicate(`http://${SG_URL}/${DB_NAME}`, DB_NAME, REPLICATION_OPTIONS)
     .then(res => {
       console.log('replicate:' + util.inspect(res, {showHidden: false, depth: null}) )

       })
}
repl()
```

Thank you !

Comment: If the replication is continuous (which is the case in [this example](https://github.com/jmn8718/RNCouchbaseExample/blob/master/app/index.js#L50-L52)) then it will automatically monitor the network using reachability APIs of the platform.  Are you observing this on iOS or Android? Or does it happen on both?

Comment: Also, what are the steps you took to switch between offline/online, using airplane mode or stopping Sync Gateway? For how long?